# Java RSA and AES Encryption Implementation

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes, rsa

I had this python code

RSA encryption

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64

def rsa_encrypt(pempubkey,plain_text): 
       rsaPublicKey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(RSA.importKey(pempubkey)) 
       cipher_text = rsaPublicKey.encrypt(plain_text)
       return base64.b64encode(cipher_text)

plain_text = "This is the RSA 2048bit key enctypted text"
pempubkey = open("publicKey.pem").read() 
b64_cipher_text = rsa_encrypt(pempubkey,plain_text)
print "Cipher text (Base64 string):",b64_cipher_text
```

AES encryption

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES,PKCS1_OAEP 
from Crypto import Random
import base64

def pkcs7Padding(data):
        length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
        data += chr(length)*length
        return data

def aes_encrypt(plain_text,key,iv):
      plain_text = pkcs7Padding(plain_text)
      cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) 
      cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(plain_text) 
      b64_cipher_text = base64.b64encode(cipher_text) 
      return b64_cipher_text

key = Random.new().read(32);
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
data = "This string was AES-256 / CBC / PKCS Padding encrypted."

cipher_text = aes_encrypt(data,key,iv)
print cipher_text
```

I am trying to implement the same in Java as below

```
public class CryptoHandler {
    private static final String RSA_PUBLIC_KEY     = "this is the rsa public key";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION_AES = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION_RSA = "RSA/None/OAEPPadding";
    private static final String ALGORITHM_AES      = "AES";
    private static final String ALGORITHM_RSA      = "RSA";

    @Nullable
    public static String encryptUsingAES(String 32charKey, String 16charIV, String data) {
        try {
            byte[] srcBuff = data.getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM_AES);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_AES);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            cipher.getBlockSize();
            byte[] dstBuff = cipher.doFinal(srcBuff);
            return Base64.toBase64String(dstBuff);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Logger.logException(exception);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    public static String encryptUsingRSA(String data) {
        try {
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(RSA_PUBLIC_KEY.getBytes()));
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM_RSA);
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_RSA);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey);
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.toBase64String(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to run both codes but I was getting different output. What is the missing in my java code?

Note: I am working in client side so i got no private key, my side is to encrypt the data and send to backend to decrypt

Comment: Please format the code correctly and sensibly.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I had formatted the code

Comment: @Topaco i had formatted the code and i found out that RSA giving different output

Comment: @Topaco as I mentioned, i got no private key, only got the public key. so my side is unable to decrypt it

Comment: @Topaco I had debug with my ios guy.

Swift
`PH\/fpV6rpm8PnLJPjRZ9FWyEOKerQrrAChPPgnIGznSJVgqKUA3TiUl5X2w0eKuA0p++\/AF0siGmdwgEl4YkKGJNKx0P02JMfsXm1neWRP+fY6BPhDVnq0wogCWy\/W1GPAaES+1C0gaOnXw+73PzgOY+cD2UCvxeiAcT0p4+lpQD1Oduz7qIYqVgzZm5K4dmKfKTNMcL9uU7QNrkHIFD6N1GdcvRUVvsZVQlPUTxD11U7jE\/0ZGO1xwIbQwNWznduyHLigPNy2+NOagufPNHBp\/IcAfR6FKyemu\/7HGU0LaGDrUhyxpc0IssNPqzVT8ksfU9RhADYWsLuXC28VU+gl+mUKOGKTW8fea2zaEdO2xs3FChD36e8CA6X4cuf9br1tIjj7Uk7CSjTwxFZfMf2A==`

Comment: Java:
zKgPde9sA1IY4Qaa9jVRdL85fOFpopyWfjQ/a7sU3+CcJn0lM07Ryq487mZt9OWz1YMufHD7kkFfGBjqaJVDhRYCCPreda2t5knwX+O3m6KGtBv6nL6xH3f/MSxKXF7g/SEnl1qWrsQxPjKQk9llvowyORl7Etnk4CczZk2reNF5gAU7AKjnzjsBWOEjZfHvFl2h+ksnR9IxnU/paoxkE4FfkR0I/2HOO5GqmrZsHezecMmbJV9zZsyVoZDVRXrtl8caPfhOAOPgFXO56zPj8ojseiqXf4MfidU/lKXg2Dbt1ucuMzkiPeebzOODw6kj8haBVQwSFj3NNRWgqZU0vMEUYU1apP6ZzD7RaMtzlX33ABWs337Kz+uSdGMpFlC/+PvjmjWtJ2ydGw2PsRmpng==

Comment: both using same aes encrypted and same data

Comment: @Topaco basically my side and ios encrypt a static data with same key and iv, then we found out that both result are discrepancy.

Comment: @Topaco iOS side is working, the encrypted data is able to decrypt by backend

Comment: @Topaco swift and java side both are using the same `Key`, `IV` and `plaintext`. Then after encrypted with AES, both side give different outlet

Comment: After that, we try to decrypt the respective AES cipher text in https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption which both also able to decrypt and get back the plain text